# .net Runtime doesn't probe plugin folder

Tags: c#, revit-api

We have a .net plugin for an application that does not load a dependent library from  the plugin folder.
Scenario:
Application (`Revit.exe` in `program files`) -> Loads plugin from `c:\programdata\revit\plugindir\ourplugindir\<plugin.dll+dependencies>`

On most machines, the load works fine. For the context of the issue, the dll dependencies are as follows

- `Revit.exe` loads `plugin.dll` (`revit.exe` is in `programfiles`, plugins are in a separate predefined directory under `programdata`)
- `plugin.dll` loads `IdentityModel.dll` (in `ourplugindir` directory)
- `IdentityModel.dll` loads `System.Text.Encodings.Web.DLL` (in `ourplugindir`)

Successful probing looks like this:
`IdentityModel` requires `System.Text.Encodings.Web.DLL`

**Initiate probing**

- Check GAC (fail)
- Check root folder where Revit.exe is present (fail)
- Check private sub folders where Revit.ext is present (fail)
- Check `ourplugindir` (success)

On the machine where the plugin load fails, for some reason **it does not probe `ourplugindir`** and is hence unable to find `System.Text.Encodings.Web.DLL`.

The plugin dll is built using .net 4.7. The dependency is an indirect dependency.

From MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies

> Assembly location can also be determined using the current binding
> context. This most often occurs when the Assembly.LoadFrom method is
> used and in COM interop scenarios. If an assembly uses the LoadFrom
> method to reference another assembly, the calling assembly's location
> is considered to be a hint about where to find the referenced
> assembly.

Since the plugins are dynamically loaded by Revit.exe, I can only assume that the application uses `Assembly.LoadFrom` or something similar to load the plugins.

So the question is, why does the runtime correctly probe and find the dependent dll in the plugin folder on some machines while it doesn't probe the same folder on other machines?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an [assembly resolver](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2014/05/rvtva3c-assembly-resolver.html)?

Comment: I did see this post while I was investigating this problem. My question is, why does this need to be done? And also, why does it work on some machines and not others?
It is extremely unsettling that you need elaborate code like this for an assembly to load a dependent dll.